# On MacOSX, *.zip can't match a-b.zip just ab.zip, how can I fix this?

Tags: wildcards, zip

I try to run `sh fizmyzip.sh` to remove some unnecessary files from all zip files under my current folder. `fizmyzip.sh` is:

```
zip -d *.zip __MACOSX/\*
zip -d *.zip "*/.DS_Store"
```

However, it can't match `a-b.zip`, just `ab.zip`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shell expands `*.zip` to `ab.zip a-b.zip`, so the commands become

```
zip -d ab.zip a-b.zip __MACOSX/\*
zip -d ab.zip a-b.zip "*/.DS_Store"
```

There should be only one target zip file in the argument after the `-d` flag. The other arguments are the files/patterns to be deleted. That is why it only works for `ab.zip`.

So use a for loop:

```
for zipf in *.zip; do zip -d "$zipf" "__MACOSX/*" "*/.DS_Store"; done
```